# How to redefine the endnote title while using biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex-chicago, endnotes

While using BibLaTeX-Chicago, I would like to change the title of the endnote section from 'Notes' to 'Endnotes'. The standard way of doing this using `\renewcommand{\notesname}{End note}` from the Endnotes package does not work for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}

\renewcommand{\notesname}{End note}

\begin{document}

Body text\endnote{Note text}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

[biblatex-chicago](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago) employs its own mechanism which involves a macro called `headername` (see section 4.4.4, p. 88 of the biblatex-chicago manual, November 17, 2022.). In the [package's code](https://github.com/jfine2358/temp-texlive-texmf-dist-tex/blob/36beb2584249e502ba64c354e6fb9e32d1449bd2/texlive2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/cmsendnotes.sty#L293), it is defined like so:

```
\def\theendnotesbypart@i[#1]{%
  \ifx\cms@end@headername\@empty
  \def\cms@end@headername{\notesname}\fi
  \theendnotesbypart@ii[#1]{\cms@end@headername}}%
```

Any help on how to redefine this, much appreciated! Just to be clear that this is for use on Overleaf so redefining the package itself is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine it close to your call to `\theendnotes`. This is actually documented in `biblatex-chicago`'s manual:

> If you’d like to redefine any of the `\*name` commands, the best place to do so is very near to where you actually print the endnotes, where it can override the definitions in the `.lbx` files (or in `babel`'s files).

So:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{document}

Body text\endnote{Note text}

\renewcommand{\notesname}{End note}
\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment:  That works! David Fussner also suggested that to me as a workaround but I avoided it because, given that this is for a journal with an endnote section at the end of each piece, I thought I'd need to set that Every. Single. Time. But it only needs to be set once - and not even before you print your endnotes with the `\theendnotes` macro. Putting `\renewcommand{\notesname}{End note}` just after `\begin{document}` works just as well, and for every endnote section in journal. Isn't it amazing how much time one can loose by barking up the wrong tree! Anyway, thank you!

Comment: You need to take some care there, if you change languages along the document for example. If you don't, you might get away with a hook in the preamble. If not, you may, for example, redefine `\enoteheading` to include your `\renewcommand{\notesname}{End note}` at every call to `\theendnotes`.

Comment: As in, if I wanted to write 'Endnotes' in another language or so on? It's an English-language journal so I think that's not an issue.  Thanks for thinking this through - that hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: As in, if you used `babel` and called `\selectlanguage` somewhere in your document. But, given the case, you should be fine.